# Is the group $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ known?

Tags: fields, absolute-galois-group, galois-groups

The automorphism group of the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ and the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ are amongst the most mysterious and worst understood objects in Galois theory and group theory.

Is there a good (= "better") description of the "intermediate group" $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ ?

Is this group better understood, or is it as mysterious ?

Comment: $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ is as big and messy as $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})$, and for precisely the same reason: there's a load of algebraically independent transcendental elements in $\mathbb{C}$ which you can essentially permute as you which. Not sure if my comment is very satisfying as an answer, maybe there's more to be said (?)

Comment: Does $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb C/\overline{\mathbb Q})$ just mean $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb C/\overline{\mathbb Q})$?  I am not accustomed to the ‘$\operatorname{Gal}$’ notation for non-algebraic extensions, though I know there are different conventions.

Comment: This group has cardinal $2^c=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$

Comment: But "big and messy" doesn't mean there's nothing to say. For instance one can wonder whether it's simple ($\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{C})=\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbf{Q}\text{-alg}}(\mathbf{C})$ is not simple because it admits $\mathrm{Aut}(\bar{\mathbf{Q}})$ as a quotient). A natural related question is whether it has a trivial abelianization.

Comment: Also one known thing is that this group is torsion-free. Indeed, the group $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{C})$ has only one non-identity conjugacy class of elements of finite order, and it consists of elements of order 2 (and this also forms the only nontrivial conjugacy class of finite subgroups). These elements map nontrivially on $\mathrm{Aut}(\bar{\mathbf{Q}})$, hence the kernel $\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbf{Q}\text{-alg}}(\mathbf{C})$ is torsion-free.